# 13" Macbook pro keyboard, trackpad & USB not working

Tags: mac, macbook, macbook-pro, macbook-pro-retina

When I open the screen, the keyboard and track pad is unresponsive.
The power button works.
USB in both sides give out power, I tried plugging in the laptop cooler and it worked.
But USBs do not connect to devices, tried mouse, keyboard, iphone.
Battery and charging it works.

It sit on the same desk for 10 hours before I tried opening it again.
I cleaned up the screen with humid napkin, then dried it up while it was closed.

I live in a country without apple stores, what should I do know?

Comment: What might have caused this? We have some symptoms, but no real causes

Comment: If I knew the cause, I probably might have figured out an answer :/ No dropping, no hitting, no software problems, no overheating

Answer (score 0):

If you've rebooted and it still isn't working, and a connected usb mouse or trackpad **is** working, your trackpad quite possibly needs replacement. First try a USB peripheral, keyboard and mouse if you have them. If they are working, it would seem to be hardware issue with your Macbook. Replacing the keyboard is a very involved process and I would not recommend attempting yourself if you're not experienced. [You can locate Apple authorized support options here](https://locate.apple.com)

Comment: I can't reboot. Its on sleep mode. Connected USB mouse is not working. The USB only gives out power to devices that only use power. It doesn't transfer data unfortunately.